# display the recent assignment of all employee

Tags: sql-server

display all the employee assignments not only the latest assignment of all employee

```
casilac    engineer       2014-05-02    Bldg.1&2 School
casilac    Leadman        2012-06-04    Office
escobarte  Engineer       2010-08-07    School
escobarte  Operator       2011-09-02    Covered Court
hambala    Supervisor     2012-06-08    Supermarket
hambala    warehouseman   2014-07-07    Covered Court 
hambala    Safety Officer 2014-08-06    Tapinac house

SELECT e.name,
   a.position,a.datestarted,
   p.ProjectName
from (constructiondb.dbo.employeetb e
INNER JOIN constructiondb.dbo.assignmenttb a
ON e.IDNo=a.IDNo)
INNER JOIN constructiondb.dbo.ProjectTB p
ON a.projectid=p.Projectid
WHERE e.employeestatus='active'
```

Expected Output:

```
casilac    engineer       2014-05-02    Bldg.1&2 School
escobarte  Operator       2011-09-02    Covered Court
hambala    Safety Officer 2014-08-06    Tapinac house
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using correlated subquery

```
SELECT e.name,a.position,a.datestarted,p.ProjectName
from constructiondb.dbo.employeetb e INNER JOIN constructiondb.dbo.assignmenttb a
ON e.IDNo=a.IDNo
INNER JOIN constructiondb.dbo.ProjectTB p ON a.projectid=p.Projectid
WHERE e.employeestatus='active' 
and a.datestarted in 
  (select max(aa.datestarted) from assignmenttb aa where e.idNo=aa.idno group by aa.idno)
```

OR you can use `row_number()` window function

```
select * from
(
    SELECT e.name,a.position,a.datestarted,p.ProjectName, 
    row_number() over(partition by e.name order by a.datestarted desc) as rn
    from constructiondb.dbo.employeetb e INNER JOIN constructiondb.dbo.assignmenttb a
    ON e.IDNo=a.IDNo
    INNER JOIN constructiondb.dbo.ProjectTB p ON a.projectid=p.Projectid
    WHERE e.employeestatus='active' 
)A where rn=1
```